# Dice 10000 probability of not scoring

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

There is a dice game I played recently, called "Dice 10,000", that is very similar to Farkle but a little simpler. In the version I played (house rules) a person scores on any given turn if they get at least three of a kind, or at least one of the die is a 1 or at least 1 of the die is a 5. On a player's first roll, they toss 6 die: I attempted to calculate how likely it is that a person does not score any points on their first roll, but I feel like the final value is too high. Is there anything incorrect following logic?

Let A = The probability of at least one die being a 1
   B = The probability of at least one die being a 5
   C = The probability of getting at least three of a kind

Then, the probability of not scoring is ${P(\neg A \cap \neg B \cap \neg C)}$

${P(\neg A \cap \neg B \cap \neg C) = P((\neg A \cap \neg B)\cap \neg C)}$
               
${= P(\neg A \cap \neg B) \times P(\neg C \: |\: \neg A \cap \neg B)}$

The probability of not getting a 1 and not getting a 5, then is:
${P(\neg A \cap \neg B) = \frac{4^{6}}{6^{6}}}$

And the probability of not getting at least 3 of one kind given you do not have any 1's or 5's is:
${P(\neg C \: |\: \neg A \cap \neg B) = 1 - \frac{\sum\limits_{i=3}^6\binom{4}{1}\binom{6}{i}3^{6-i}}{4^{6}}}$

Since there are 6 die, there is a possibility that the player has 3 of a kind for two separate values (for instance three 4's and three 2's are rolled), so I am particularly concerned with my calculation for ${P(\neg C \: |\: \neg A \cap \neg B)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to directly count the number of ways where you don't get three of a kind using just $2,3,4,6$. There are ${4 \choose 3}  \frac{6!}{(2!)^3} = 360$ ways to do it with three pairs and ${4 \choose 2}  \frac{6!}{(2!)^2} = 1080$ ways to do it with two pairs and two separate rolls. So the final probability becomes $\frac{360+1080}{6^6} \approx 0.0309$.

Comment: Why do you divide by 6^6 at the end? Shouldn't it be divided by 4^6, since we removed 1 and 5 as possibilities?

Comment: I was immediately calculating the probability $P(\neg A \cap \neg B \cap \neg C)$. If you want $P(\neg C | \neg A \cap \neg B)$ then divide by $4^6$.

Comment: Oh I see. Can you explain the reasoning for (4 choose 3) * 6!/(2!)^3? I'm new to counting and I had a hard time count the probability directly originally, which is why I tried using the given condition.

Comment: First you have to choose the three numbers that appear in the pairs, this can be done in $4 \choose 3$ ways. Then you have to find the number of different permutations in which these numbers (for example $223344$) can appear. There are $6!$ ways to permute six elements, and we divide by $(2!)^3$ because we don't want to count whenever two of the same number are swapped. The calculation for two pairs and two lone rolls is very similar.